# How to populate fields which types are "mongoose.types.mixed"?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

i ran into a problem with populating "mixed" type fields in my mongoose documents.
Here is my schema:

```
    changed: [
      {
        field: String,
        fieldToPopulate: String,
        from: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
          refPath: 'changed.fieldToPopulate'
        },
        to: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
          refPath: 'changed.fieldToPopulate'
        }
      }
    ]
```

the 'changed.from' and 'changed.to' fields can have number, string, date and ObjectId types.
when i'm trying to get data and populate **'changed.from'** **'changed.to'** fields (if it's ObjectId), everything is working, but for 'changed.from/to' fields which have numbers or string type populate returns **'null'** (because he can't find documents)

so, what can you advise me?

I thought about giving condition to populate, like "populate only if field is ObjectId", but i don't know how to do it, and is it even possible?